# Add ImageSource with SharpAvi

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using [SharpAvi](https://github.com/baSSiLL/SharpAvi) and I want add image. I have ImageSource in bytes and I can't write image to stream. I getting this exception:

> "System.ArgumentException: 'Buffer size is not sufficient.'"

In documentation I read I need write DIB. How to convert ImageSource to Windows DIB?

```
//I convert canvas to Imagesource bytes
byte[] canvasdata = CanvasWriter.SaveCanvasToImgSimulate(canvas, (int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height);

var writer = new AviWriter("test.avi")
{
    FramesPerSecond = 30,
    // Emitting AVI v1 index in addition to OpenDML index (AVI v2)
    // improves compatibility with some software, including 
    // standard Windows programs like Media Player and File Explorer
    EmitIndex1 = true
};

var stream  = writer.AddMotionJpegVideoStream((int)data.CanvasW, (int)data.CanvasH, 70);

stream.WriteFrame(true, canvasdata, 0, canvasdata.Length);

writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved problem by using this function:

```
    private byte[] BitmapSourceToArray(BitmapSource bitmapSource)
    {
        // Stride = (width) x (bytes per pixel)
        int stride = (int)bitmapSource.PixelWidth * (bitmapSource.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
        byte[] pixels = new byte[(int)bitmapSource.PixelHeight * stride];

        bitmapSource.CopyPixels(pixels, stride, 0);

        return pixels;
    }
```